# Elastic Beanstalk Aws Django static and media files

Tags: django, amazon-s3, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I'am having troubles to access to my media files after uploading them, i have a store website where the admin can add items and their images, i have two separated root folders:
/static : for static files
/Prod : for the product files

Here is my setting.py:

```
...

BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
PROJECT_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))

...
...

STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(PROJECT_DIR, 'static', 'Prod')
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
]
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(PROJECT_DIR, 'Prod')
MEDIA_URL = '/Prod/'
```

when i check the images URL they are correct: mywebsitw.com/prod/image.jpg but they are not displayed and the direct url do not display any image, knowing that the image is uploaded in the correct directory

PS: in my local virtual envirenment it works perfectly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For those who had the same issue, I just switched to S3 for dynamic storage (linked to db) and kept the static file for (CSS, JS, static images...).

you need to add some packages: Boto3, django-storages.

there is many good tuto on the net just search for: django s3 upload files